# Does working out affect breast-feeding?

Tags: breastfeeding

I am wondering if working out will affect the milk production of a mama. Is it only intense working out that affects milk or any kind of exercise? What should moms be watching out for when trying to get back in shape but still breastfeeding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exercise does not affect your milk production. However, hydration does. Make sure, whether working out or not, to drink plenty of water.

If you notice that your baby does not want to nurse after a work out, they may not enjoy the taste of sweat. Clean the area and see if that helps.

You may also want to pump or nurse before a workout to reduce the heavy feeling, especially during cardio sessions.